# Prove $\int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_a^cf(x)\,\mathrm dx+\int_c^bf(x)\,\mathrm dx$ without the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function. Let $a,b,c$ be constants, with $a < c < b$. Prove that

$\displaystyle\int_a^b f(x)dx = \int_a^c f(x)dx + \int_c^b f(x)dx$ $(*)$

In particular, I would like to see a proof of this property that does not use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. I am aware that this can be easily proved using the Fundamental Theorem. However, the proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus that I understand the most is the one given in James Stewart's Calculus. As it turns out, the property $(*)$ is actually used by Stewart in order to prove the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus!

As far as actually proving $(*)$ without using the Fundamental Theorem, the only thing I can think of is to use Riemann sums

$\displaystyle  \int_a^b f(x)dx = \lim_{ n \to \infty } \sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i) \frac {b-a}{n}$

$\displaystyle  \int_a^c f(x)dx + \int_c^b f(x)dx = \lim_{ n \to \infty } \sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i) \frac {c-a}{n} + \lim_{ m \to \infty } \sum_{j=1}^m f(x_j) \frac {b-c}{m}$

Not sure what to do next, since $x_i \neq x_j$ in general. Similarly $m = n$ is not necessarily true.

Comment: See: https://math.libretexts.org/Courses/Monroe_Community_College/MTH_210_Calculus_I/Chapter_5%3A_Integration/Xtra_full_5.3%3A_includes_Proof_of_The_Fundamental_Theorem_of_Calculus you have to scrolll down a bit though. Also the last line in the proof regarding your question is $F(b)-F(a)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{f(c_i)\Delta{x}}=\int^b_a{f(x)}dx$

Comment: What's your definition of Riemann-integral? There are about 3 equivalent definitions.

Comment: @ε-δ The one given in the Stewart Calculus books

Comment: And do you think everybody who reads this question knows these books or will bother to look that up?

Comment: Is that your definition for the Riemann integral, where the spacing between $x$ values is always $1/n$? It doesn't act well on functions like $f(x)=1$ if $x$ is rational, $f(x)=0$ if $x$ is irrational.

Comment: @aschepler I would just like to point out that I am assuming that $f$ is a continuous function. Your $f(x)$ is not continuous anywhere.

Comment: This statement holds for Riemann integrable functions in general, no need to assume continuity.

Comment: Sure. I was more curious because that definition would imply some functions are integrable, even though they aren't. I'm also in some doubt your question even can be proved using only that definition.

Comment: You could try: $$\int_a^bf(x)\ dx = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n f\left(a+\frac{i}n(b-a)\right)\frac{b-a}n$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**

To see this you need to work with Riemann sums in general, not just with the case of partitions of equal length.

Consider a partition $P: a=a_0<...<a_n=c$ of $[a,c]$, and some intermediate points $x_1^*,.., x_n^*$. Consider also a partition $Q: c=b_0<...<b_m=b$ of $[c,b]$, and some intermediate points $y_1^*,.., y_m^*$.

Then the sum of the corresponding Riemann sums
$$\sum_{k=1}^n f(x_k^*)(a_k-a_{k-1})+\sum_{k=1}^m f(y_k^*)(b_k-b_{k-1})$$

is a Riemann sum for $\int_a^b f(t)dt$ for the partition 
$$P \cup Q= a_0<a_1<...<a_n<b_1<...<b_m=b$$
and the intermediate points $x_1^*,.., x_n^*,y_1^*,.., y_m^*$.

Note here that $\| P \cup Q \| = \max\{ \|P \|, \| Q \| \}$.

Conversely, if you have a partition $P: a=a_0< a_1< ...< a_n =b$, let $k$ be the last index for which $a_k \leq c$. Then $a_{k+1}>c$.

Now, for any intermediate points $x_1,..., x_n$ show that $P': a_0<a_1<...<a_k <c$ (or $P': a_0<a_1<...<a_k =c$) and $Q': c< a_{k+1}<....<a_n=b$ are partitions  of $[a,c], [c,b]$ and that $x_1^*,.., x_{k-1}^*, c$ and $x_{k}^*,.., x_n^*$ are intermediate points.

If $R$ is the corresponding Riemann sum for $P$ , and $R_1,R_2$ are the corresponding Riemann sums for $P',Q'$, show that 
$$|R-R_1-R_2 | < 2\|P\| M$$
where $$M= \sup\{ |f(x)| : x \in [a,b]\}$$

Comment: Nice answer. Except for the part where you misspelled intermediate.

Comment: Also, is there a reason why you have $a_k - a_{k-1}$ in both Riemann suns?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming we know additivity of integral, if we define
$$
\begin{split}
f_{ab} &= 
\begin{cases}
f(x) & x \in [a,b] \\
0 & x \not\in [a,b]
\end{cases}\\
f_{cb} &= 
\begin{cases}
f(x) & x \in [c,b] \\
0 & x \not\in [c,b]
\end{cases}\\
f_{ac} &= 
\begin{cases}
f(x) & x \in [a,c] \\
0 & x \not\in [a,c]
\end{cases}\\
\end{split}
$$

Then

$$
\begin{split}
\int_a^b f(x) \,\operatorname d x &= \int_{\mathbb R}f_{ab}(x)\, \operatorname d x  \\
\int_a^c f(x)\, \operatorname d x &= \int_{\mathbb R}f_{ac}(x) \,\operatorname d x  \\
\int_b^c f(x) \,\operatorname d x &= \int_{\mathbb R}f_{bc}(x) \,\operatorname d x  \\
\end{split}
$$

Therefore, since $
f_{ab} = f_{ac}+f_{cb} 
$, we get
$$
\begin{split}
\int_a^b f(x) \,\operatorname d x& =\int_{\mathbb R} f_{ab}(x) \,\operatorname d x \\
&= \int_{\mathbb R} \left(f_{ac}(x) + f_{cb}(x) \right)\,\operatorname d x \\
&= \int_{\mathbb R} f_{ac}(x)\, \operatorname d x +  \int_{\mathbb R}f_{cb}(x) \,\operatorname d x \\
&= \int_a^c f(x)\,\operatorname d x + \int_c^b f(x)\, \operatorname d x
\end{split}
$$

Comment: Very clever (+1)

Comment: Except depending where we're starting from, you may now have to relate $\int_{\mathbb{R}}$ to the given definition of a proper integral.

Comment: I think the theorem in the OP may be used in the proof that a function with a jump (like yours) is Riemann integrable.